# Stripes + GAE how to upload a file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, stripes

I'd like to implement file uploading in my app. The problem of stripes + gae is that stripes stores uploaded files locally before processing them, and gae does not allow that.

I've decided to use GCS and blobstore API for files uploading but faced with problems.

My page code looks like:

```
<form action="${actionBean.servletUploadUrl}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And my server side code I tried to implement in two ways:

**1.**
getServletUploadUrl() is like

```
public String getServletUploadUrl() {
   String bucket = "my-bucket";
   BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
   UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName(bucket);
   return blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/MyActionBean.action?saveDocument=", uploadOptions);
}
```

In that way I get an exception: `Could not construct a MultipartWrapper for the current request.`

**2.**
(Almost the same but tried to use servlet)

getServletUploadUrl() is like

```
public String getServletUploadUrl() {
    String bucket = "my-bucket";
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName(bucket);
    return blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/docUpload", uploadOptions);
}
```

where `/docUpload` is mapped in web.xml to `DocumentUploadServlet` where I implemented `doPost` method.

I got to that servlet but I'd like to go to `saveDocument()` method in my action bean after that. I added line

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/MyActionBean.action?saveDocument=").forward(req, resp);
```

And again as in my 1st way I get an exception: `Could not construct a MultipartWrapper for the current request.`

Seems the problem is that Stripes can not wrap request as both exceptions look like this:

```
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesRuntimeException: Could not construct a MultipartWrapper for the current request.
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.multipart.DefaultMultipartWrapperFactory.wrap(DefaultMultipartWrapperFactory.java:158)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesRequestWrapper.constructMultipartWrapper(StripesRequestWrapper.java:126)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesRequestWrapper.<init>(StripesRequestWrapper.java:106)
at net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter.wrapRequest(StripesFilter.java:295)
```

Probably there are better ways of file uploading. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Do you have apache commons fileupload in your classpath? Also, you mentioned "The problem of stripes + gae is that stripes stores uploaded files locally before processing them, and gae does not allow that". Have you considered storing the file in the session?

Comment: Did you finally solved that? Could you please help me posting the code? or we can chat by email or PM